# Different height and position for col in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wrote this code for insert image in order to create a grid full of photos:

```
<section class="gallery-section">

    <div class="container grid-custom" style="padding-top: 50px;">
      <div class="row">

        <div style="padding: 0px;" class="text-center col-md-4 gallery-image">
          <img src="./images/cover.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

        <div style="padding: 0px;" class="my-auto text-center col-md-4 gallery-image">
          <img src="./images/passero.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

        <div style="padding: 0px;" class="text-center col-md-4 gallery-image">
          <img src="./images/cigno.JPG" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div style="padding: 0px;" class="text-center col-md-4 gallery-image">
          <img src="./images/pic1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

        <div style="padding: 0px;" class="text-center col-md-4 gallery-image">
          <img src="./images/fiore.JPG" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

        <div style="padding: 0px;" class="text-center col-md-4 gallery-image">
          <img src="./images/sfondo7.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

But I get this result:
[image]

What should I do instead to get a result like this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are placing 3 images per `div.row`, which results in this layout:

[image]

As you can see, the `div.row` elements are stacked, and each `div.row` is as high as its highest image, creating gaps for the remaining space in each row.

In summary, you have divided the grid **first by rows, and then by columns**.

What you need is a [masonry grid](https://w3bits.com/css-masonry/). As opposite to your approach, this grid is divided **first by columns, and then by rows or images**.

The main concept behind a masonry grid resides in an approach like this:

```html
<!-- Left column -->
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="" alt="Top image">
    <img src="" alt="Middle image">
    <img src="" alt="Bottom image">
</div>

<!-- Center column -->
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="" alt="Top image">
    <img src="" alt="Middle image">
    <img src="" alt="Bottom image">
</div>

<!-- Right column -->
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="" alt="Top image">
    <img src="" alt="Middle image">
    <img src="" alt="Bottom image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a `Masonry Layout`.

There are a lot of websites that give nice tutorials. Here for instance I would refer to https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/